# Rails + Angular : Issue with directive

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have Rails 4.2.4 and Angular 1.4.8.

I am trying define a directive:

index.html:

```
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller='myController'>
    <foo bar='bar'></foo>
</div>
```

app.js:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['templates']);

angular.module('myApp', ['templates']).directive('foo', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        scope: {
            bar: '='
        },
        templateUrl: 'bar.html'

    }
});

angular.module('myApp').controller('myController', function($scope, $http){
    $scope.bar = "XMan";
});
```

bar.html:

```
<h1> Hi {{ bar }}! </h1>
<ng-include src="'{{bar}}.html'"
```

XMan.html:

```
<p>Hello I'm XMan</p>
```

---

Here I am expecting my foo directive to render

```
<h1> Hi X Man! </h1>
<p> Hello I'm XMan </p>
```

but I am getting

```
<h1> Hi {{ bar }}! </h1>
<!-- ngInclude: undefined -->
```

---

What is wrong with my approach. Please guide me; I am very new to Angular.js.

Comment: I think bar.html path will wrong (or), on first case you have made some mistake in control loading.


correct : for directive
angular.module('myApp', ['templates']).directive('foo', ......

wrong: for controller
angular.module('myApp').controller('myController', ...... means you missed up dependency injection of ['templates'] for controller defination

Comment: @saikumar When I try `angular.module('myApp', ['templates']).controller(...` my directive is not loading at all! :(

Comment: try to set `ng-app='myApp' ` to body instead of that div. I think ng-app must be at least parent of element with controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution. We cannot bind `ng-include` `src` with `scope` variable.

Instead I used function call to get the source then it works!

That is I changed

```
<ng-include src="'{{bar}}.html'"
```

to

```
<ng-include src="barUrl()"
```

and added a controller scope function:

```
$scope.barUrl = function(){
    return $scope.bar + '.html'
}
```